# Explicit cast to Implicit cast in C

Tags: c, casting

I was wondering if it was possible to return the same result with only 1 explicit cast ?

```c
void *begin(void *pt, size_t size)
{
    return (void*)((size_t)pt & -size);
}
```

Every time in tried I got a BAD_ACCESS code 1

Exemple:

```c
void *begin(void *pt, size_t size)
{   
    size_t *tmp = pt;
    size_t res = *tmp & -size;
    return (void*)(res);
}
```

Comment: Your second code essentially does `*(int *)pt & -size` (_dereferences_ `pt`), which is not the same as `(size_t)pt & -size`

Comment: Your second example is not a correct rewriting of your first.  In your second example, you've changed `size_t` to `size_t *`, which is quite different.

Comment: `(void*)((size_t)pt & -size)` generates a questionable pointer when `size_t` is narrower than `void *`.  Research `uintptr_t`.

Comment: Regis, what is the goal of `begin()`?  How is code really using that?

Comment: Re the change from `int` to `size_t`: ForceBru’s comment was not about the use of `int` versus `sizez_t` but was about the use of, in effect, either `* (int *) pt` or `* (size_t) pt`. That expression is the effect of your code `size_t *tmp = pt;` followed by the statement that uses `*tmp`. The `*` part of `*tmp` attempts to get data from the memory where `tmp` points, but that is not what you want to do. You want to be using the value of `pt`, not data from where it points.

Comment: Re “Explicit cast to Implicit cast”: There is no such thing as an implicit cast in C. A cast is the operator `(type)`. It is always explicit; a cast does not exist in source code unless somebody puts it there. A cast performs a conversion. There are implicit conversions in C, in assignments and other places.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done with zero casts, with implementation-dependent code. However, this is akin to writing code without using the letter “e”: It may be a challenge, but it serves no purpose in production code. If it is posed as an academic exercise, it can be useful because artificial constraints can induce a student to think about things they might not otherwise think about so much, like alternative ways to do things or the technical rules of the language. However, in practice, this is generally pointless.

Your sample code uses `size_t`, but the preferred type for working with address as integers is `uintptr_t`, if it is defined. If it is defined, it is defined in `<stdint.h>`, and any normal C implementation of even modest quality should define it.

Your sample code assumes that converting an address to `size_t` yields a plain integer address in memory. (The `address & -size` operation is a common way of finding an address aligned to a multiple of `size`, which must be a power of two, by clearing the low bits, and so we recognize that your `(size_t) pt` must be a plain address, at least in its low bits.) Instead, let us assume that a pointer is represented in memory using a plain integer for the address and is the same size as `uintptr_t`. In any C implementation in which either of these true, the other is likely true too. Before using the following code, you should confirm this for your target C implementations.

Given that assumption, we can implement your `begin` routine with no casts:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>

void *begin(void *pt, size_t size)
{
    uintptr_t us = size;        // Convert size to uintptr_t to ensure it is at least as wide.
    uintptr_t x;                // Make space to copy pointer.
    memcpy(&x, &pt, sizeof x);  // Copy bytes.
    x &= -us;                   // Zero low bits.
    memcpy(&pt, &x, sizeof pt); // Copy bytes back.
    return pt;
}
```

If the assumption is not true, it is nonetheless possible to implement `begin` for any chosen C implementation by setting an `unsigned char` pointer with `unsigned char *p = (unsigned char *) &pt;` and then using `p` to examine and manipulate the bytes of `pt`. The C standard requires each implementation to document its representation of types, so the meanings of the bytes in the `void *` `pt` must be documented, which enables writing code to compute with them as desired.

That uses one cast. It could be reduced to zero with `void *v = &pt; unsigned char *p = v;`.

Comment: If `size_t` is narrower than `uintptr_t`, `x &= -size;` will clear MSbits of `x`.  Perhaps `uintptr_t mask = sz; x &= ~mask;` to insure the `~` is done with sufficient width.

Comment: @chux: Good point, updated, although we want `-mask`, not `~mask`. (Nightmare: `int` is wider than `uintptr_t` and not two’s complement, so `mask` gets promoted and `-mask` is not what we want!)

Comment: ~ vs. -, Hmmm, need to use higher screen magnification.